# Where can I find some good low contrast calligraphy and script fonts?

Tags: fonts, typography, font-design, calligraphy

It seems that lot of the scripts and calligraphy font I see have very high contrasts.

So I wondering if there are any ones that have medium or low contrast (paid or free fonts).

*Low contrast* uses strokes that are even width/stroke throughout the whole font.

Comment: What style of script font are you looking for? More decorative (wedding), readable or plain? Or just any script font with even strokes?

Comment: @AndrewH basically any script font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check out Typekit: [Script fonts with low contrast](https://typekit.com/fonts?classification=script&contrast=low) I would also check out the medium contrast fonts.

Also check out [Designmodo article: Script Fonts: Most Popular Typefaces, Best for Webfonts](http://designmodo.com/script-webfonts/). Note that these fonts can also be used for desktop.

Some of the notable script fonts that have even strokes from the article.

- Thirsty Script
- Aphrodite Pro (Decorative)
- Belinda
- Insolente

Comment: Thanks @AndrewH - I am leaving the question open for a few more days.

Comment: @zenuts It's been a few more days.